# Commands to control vlc

Tags: linux, vlc-media-player

I have an instance of VLC open and I want to set up some hot keys so that I can pause/play/seek without having to switch focus to VLC. Are there commands that make this possible, and if so, which?

Answer (score 3):

To customize hotkeys in VLC, go to `Settings->Preferences->Hot keys`. Over there, you'll find two columns: **Hotkey** and **Global** for each action. Set up **Global** hotkeys for the functions you want.

You will have to restart VLC for the new shortcuts to be effective.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know this feature existed. It works well for certain things like play/pause where I have keys on the keyboard that I can dedicate to it without conflicts, but there are other things that I'd like to, for example, map to a certain key in vim when in normal mode, which I can't do with global key mappings.